# How to connect to Webservice REST with POST from Power BI

Tags: rest, web-services, post, powerbi

I am trying to connect to a webservice through Power BI but I still do not achieve result, first try to use the Web data source and with the Advanced Use add the Header that in my case is `Content-Type` and its value is `application/json` and additional as Body I have a token

[image]

Where I get as a result the following:

[image]

Additional also try to use as source "Blank Query", where I accessed the advanced editor section and add the following Query:

[image]

I get as an error the following:

[image]

To make sure that the Webservice works correctly and obtains a result I have used the Advanced REST Client tool and I have made the following configuration:

[image]

Where you can see that the Headers section I have added the `Header name Content-Typ`e and the value of the `Header Value` is `application/json`, in the `Body` section is where I have added the `token`

[image]

With this I realize that my Webservice gets an answer and that the service is working correctly, I would like someone to give me a little guidance in a short time to perform correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply the content to switch the method from GET to POST eg

> Perform a POST against a URL, passing a binary JSON payload and
> parsing the response as JSON.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents#example-2

```
let
    url = "https://postman-echo.com/post",
    headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
    postData = Json.FromValue([token = "abcdef"]),
    response = Web.Contents(
        url,
        [
            Headers = headers,
            Content = postData
        ]
    ),
    jsonResponse = Json.Document(response),
    json = jsonResponse[json]
in
    json
```

or

```
let
    url = "https://postman-echo.com/post",
    headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
    postData = Text.ToBinary("{ ""token"":""abcdef""}"),
    response = Web.Contents(
        url,
        [
            Headers = headers,
            Content = postData
        ]
    ),
    jsonResponse = Json.Document(response),
    json = jsonResponse[json]
in
    json
```

Comment: I haven't quite understood your question, do you want me to apply your sample code to my blank query?

Comment: Adding `Content` to the Web.Contents call switches the HTTP request from GET to POST.

Comment: I see that in the answer you added the Header this is correct, what I do not see is where to add the parameter I use in Body in the example I made in the Advanced REST Client application, if you look I have a token parameter, where should I add it ?

Comment: If you want the data in the request body, set it to Content as in the example

Comment: Can you add an example on how to configure the data in the request body?

Comment: See updated answer.